# how to control selection region in widgets scrolledForm

Tags: eclipse-rcp

how to control/refresh selection region in widgets scrolledForm?
first I pull down scroll bar then select some contents(include some hyper link) in formtext form bottom to up,
and then **the select area will display abnormal.**

and some code like below:

```
scrolledForm = toolkit.createScrolledForm(tabFolder);
scrolledForm.getBody().setLayout(new TableWrapLayout());
formText = toolkit.createFormText(scrolledForm.getBody(), false);
formText.setText("xxxx\nxxxx\nxxxx...", false, false)
scrolledForm.reflow(true);
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do mean by 'display abnormal', what goes wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 'display abnormal' means first, select some area(selection region color is blue), then pull down/up scroll bar, and now the origin all/partial select area is changed as white color, seems have two layer choose overlap.  by the way, my machine is RedHat 5.8, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a eclipse bug.

You can get more details from below link:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=195504